# Resolving Chakra UI issues with an existing Nextjs, Redux Toolkit app

Tags: next.js, redux-toolkit, react-dom, chakra-ui

I need help resolving the following warning when using ChakraProvider component

*"Warning react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: You are importing hydrateRoot from "react-dom" which is not supported. You should instead import it from "react-dom/client"."*

Setup: I have a working nextjs app that uses Redux toolkit. App breaks with the above warning after adding chakra UI and set up as below

```
npm i @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react@^11 @emotion/styled@^11 framer-motion@^6



import Head from "next/head";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import Layout from "../components/layout/layout";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "../store/app/store";
import { ChakraProvider, extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";
```

//The import of ChakraProvider, extendTheme alone gives this warning. App works though. However when the theme config is setup as with colors below, the site breaks even when the ChakraProvider wrapper is removed. Where could the conflict be coming from?

```
const colors = {
  brand: {
    900: "#1a365d",
    800: "#153e75",
    700: "#2a69ac",
  },
};

const theme = extendTheme({ colors });

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ChakraProvider resetCSS theme={theme}>
        <Layout>
          <Head>
            <meta
              name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
            />
            <link
              rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
            />
            <link
              rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css"
            />
          </Head>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </ChakraProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and what helped me was putting 'use client' at the top of the chakra component file.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33265351)